# Schwarzschild metric in Isotropic coordinates

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, black-holes, metric-tensor

As one wants to jump to Isotropic coordinates in order to write the [Schwarzschild metric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzschild_metric) in terms of them, one does this coordinate transformation:

$$r=r'\left(1+\frac{M}{2r'}\right)^2$$

So we start with the very well-known form:

$$ds^2 = -\left(1-\frac{2m}{r}\right)dt^2 + \left(1-\frac{2m}{r}\right)^{-1}dr^2 +r^2(d\theta^2 +\sin^2\theta d\phi^2) $$

And arrive at 
$$ ds^2 = -\left(\frac{1-M/2r'}{1+M/2r'}\right)^2dt^2 +(1+M/2r')^4[dr'^2 +r'^2( d\theta^2 +\sin^2\theta d\phi^2)]$$

My question is: Where did this coordinate transformation come from?

Comment: What happens when $r=2m$ or $r=0$?

Comment: Singularity. @KyleKanos

Comment: What you you mean with your question? Coordinate transformations don't "come" from anywhere - they are simply (suitably nice) functions of coordinates.

Comment: @PhilosophicalPhysics: Does that happen with the transformation?

Comment: No it doesn't. @ACuriousMind when I first saw this transformation, it came from $r' = 1/2(r-m+\sqrt{r^2-2m})$ But I tried to manipulate it in all ways and I still couldn't get the transformation I wrote in the question above. I am doubting the transformation I just wrote is wrong that is why I didn't mention it in the question above.

Comment: *No it doesn't.* So there's your answer: the transformation comes from the desire to not have a singularity at $r'=2m$ (there would still be one at $r'=0$ though).

Comment: There's a very good explanation of where the coordinate transformation comes from in Wang, Gui & Ma; http://ac.els-cdn.com/S0370269307006454/1-s2.0-S0370269307006454-main.pdf?_tid=59c77c92-698f-11e4-9318-00000aacb361&acdnat=1415702693_1c0b57fc87916f5bcd532ef254ab95fc

Comment: @Kyle Kanos - there's still a coordinate singularity at r'=1/2, so that's not the desire. The desire was to have the same forefactor for all spatial directions, which comes in handy when superpositionioning different fields over each other in the cartesian form (that's why they use isotropic coordinates in n-body simulations), but the r=2 is just at r'=1/2.

Answer (score 24):

The aim of the isotropic coordinates is to write the metric in the form where the spacelike slices are as close as possible to Euclidean. That is, we try to write the metric in the form:

$$ ds^2 = -A^2(r)dt^2 + B^2(r)d\Sigma^2 $$

where $d\Sigma^2$ is the Euclidean metric:

$$ d\Sigma^2 = dr^2 + r^2(d\theta^2 + \sin^2\theta d\phi^2) $$

So let's use the substitution $r\rightarrow r'$ and write down our metric:

$$ ds^2 = -\left(1-\frac{2M}{r'}\right)dt^2 + B^2(r')\left(dr'^2 + r'^2(d\theta^2 + \sin^2\theta d\phi^2)\right) $$

If we compare this with the Schwarzschild metric:

$$ ds^2 = -\left(1-\frac{2M}{r}\right)dt^2 + \frac{dr^2}{1 - 2M/r} + r^2(d\theta^2 + \sin^2\theta d\phi^2) $$

Then for the angular parts to be equal we must have:

$$ B^2(r')r'^2 = r^2 $$

And for the radial parts to be equal we must have:

$$ B^2(r')dr'^2 = \frac{dr^2}{1 - 2M/r} $$

Divide the second equation by the first to eliminate $B$ and we end up with:

$$ \frac{dr'^2}{r'^2} = \frac{dr^2}{r^2 - 2Mr} $$

Some Intermediate Steps are Integrate this
$$ \frac{dr'}{r'} = \frac{dr}{\sqrt{r^2 - 2Mr}} $$
Integration Will give
$$ \log{r'}=\log{(\frac{r-M+\sqrt{r(r-2M)}}{M})}+\log{K} $$
Where K is The Integration Constant and set K$=\frac{M}{2}$
$$ r'=\frac{r-M+\sqrt{r(r-2M)}}{2}$$
And then just take the square root and integrate and we get the substitution you describe:

$$ r = r'\left(1 + \frac{M}{2r'}\right)^2 $$

Comment: the third line in the derivation is not correct
it should read r(r')
only then the correct result also for the dt^2-term in isotropic coordiantes is obtained

Comment: Upon performing this integration, I am getting $r=\frac{r'}{2K} {(1+\frac{MK}{r'})^{2}}$, where K is the integration constant. Any idea on how to show that $K=\frac{1}{2}$?